# How to tell when element is finally shown on screen?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a "Loading" dialog that displays while I'm adding a lot of custom elements to a container.  I've set the dialog to disappear when the last added element's creationCompleteHandler is called, but the dialog disappears before all the elements display on screen (which results in a very large lag).

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var elem:MyElement = new MyElement();
    elem.name = "elem" + i;
    container.addElement(elem);

    if (i == 99) {
        elem.creationComplete = function():void {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(loadingDialog);
        };
    }
}
```

So as I've said, the dialog disappears before all the elements appear on screen.  Is there a way to tell when all the custom elements have been added AND are currently showing on screen?

**Update:**  To clarify, `elem.creationComplete` is just a custom property function that gets called when the element's creationCompleteHandler is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I followed jidma's answer, except I listened for the PropertyChanged event and decremented when the `contentHeight` property changed on the container.  This decremented only when the container's height was affected by the added element, which seemed to work.

Comment: For memory reasons, make sure you remove that event listener as soon as it is fired. You don't want the event firing each time the contentHeight is changed in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

The elements, even though they have been added in the right order, they are not created in that order:

```
        private function doStuff():void {
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(myPopup, this);
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var elem:MyElement = new MyElement();
                elem.name = "elem" + i;
                container.addElement(elem);

                elem.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function(e:FlexEvent):void {
                    trace("i'm done " + e.target.name);
                });

                if (i == 9) {
                    elem.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function():void {
                        trace("i'll remove the popup " + elem.name);
                        PopUpManager.removePopUp(myPopup);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Gives:

```
i'm done elem5
i'm done elem7
i'm done elem0
i'm done elem8
i'm done elem6
i'm done elem3
i'm done elem9
i'll remove the popup elem9
i'm done elem1
i'm done elem4
i'm done elem2
```

You need to add a global variable to check that all the elements have actually been created:

```
public var created:int = 0;

        private function doStuff():void {
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(myPopup, this);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var elem:MyElement = new MyElement();
                elem.name = "elem" + i;
                container.addElement(elem);
                created++; // <--- increment with each new element

                elem.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function(e:FlexEvent):void {
                    created--;  // <--- decrement when element is created
                    trace("i'm done ", e.target.name);
                    if (created == 0) {
                        trace("i'll remove it ", e.target.name);
                        PopUpManager.removePopUp(myPopup);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

And the result is:

```
i'm done  elem5
i'm done  elem7
i'm done  elem0
i'm done  elem8
i'm done  elem6
i'm done  elem3
i'm done  elem9
i'm done  elem1
i'm done  elem4
i'm done  elem2
i'll remove it  elem2
```

Comment: This seems like it would be the reason, but there is still a difference between when the element is created and when it is rendered on the screen, apparently.  This did not work... it's like the items are created, but not visible until after the lag.

Comment: have you tried: `callLater(PopUpManager.removePopUp, [ myPopup ]);` instead?

Comment: Thanks, this led me to the answer.